# How to schedule task with access to multiple drives?

Tags: batch-file, directory, scheduled-tasks, drive

I am attempting to run a .bat file that within itself starts a pyton script that moves files within a directory on one drive to another directory on a different drive. I can run the file by hand successfully but when I schedule a task for it, the run result is **0x80070001** and:

[image: Error when run from Task Scheduler]

The .bat file contains:

`C:\Python37-32\python.exe  "C:/wamp64/www/sgmvp_cloud_files/moveFiles.py"`

How can I adjust my .bat file or the task itself to have access to both drives? I am running the task with the highest privledge and I am authorised to *Log on as a batch job*.

Comment: Is `I:` a mapped drive or local drive.

Comment: ```I:``` is a Network Drive.